# High Score Windows Phone 8.1 VB SilverLight

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

Im trying to make it so when the user gets a score higher than the high score that it will automatically continue to count on the high score, if that makes sense, here are some of the codes that i am working with.

```
Dim Score As Integer = 0
Dim Attempted As Integer = 0
Dim HighScoreiso As Integer = 0
Dim AppScores As IsolatedStorageSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings

If Score >= HighScoreiso Then
            HighScoreText.Text = "HighScore: " & Score.ToString
            AppScores.Remove("HighScore")
            AppScores.Add("HighScore", HighScoreText.Text)
        End If
```

Comment: What is your question? http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: For example, if Score is more than the HighScore then i want it to save it to the isolated storage

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save this score in the local storage, you could use this code:

```
   Private Async Function WriteToFileAsync(content As String, folder As String, filename As String) As Task
            Dim fileBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content.ToCharArray())
            Dim local As StorageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
            Dim dataFolder = Await local.CreateFolderAsync(folder, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
            Dim file = Await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
            Using stream = Await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()
                stream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)  
            End Using
        End Function

        Private Async Function ReadFromFileAsync(folder As String, filename As String) As Task(Of String)
            Dim local As StorageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
            Dim result As String = String.Empty
            If local IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim dataFolder = Await local.GetFolderAsync(folder)
                Dim file = Await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(filename)
                Using streamReader As New StreamReader(file)
                    result = result + streamReader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End If
            Return result
        End Function
```

Comment: Hello, i can already save the score using isolated storage, my problem is when the "score" becomes higher then the "Highest Score" it doesn't change on the "Highest Score" so what i want it to do is once the "Score" is higher then the "Highest Score" it will start to count along with the "Score"